# What is a phrase or word for 'not logged in' state?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, phrasal-verbs

On a website, if you log in, you're in a **logged in** state, if you then log out, you are in a **logged out** state.

What do you call the state before you have ever logged in to a site? Is it correct to also call that being *logged out*? Is *not logged in* the same as *logged out*?

I'm looking for a word or phrase that would apply to either registered or not registered users looking at the site.

Example usage:

> We allow configuring some settings from a *not logged in* view.

Comment: If you've never logged in, presumably you are *not registered* with the site.

Comment: @TrevorD, I'm looking for a word that would apply to both registered and not registered users.

Comment: "We allow configuring some settings for unregistered users"

Comment: However, you might be registered, but have never used that registration to log in. @Gerli, is there any **practical** difference between a user who is not logged in (just encountered the site) and one who has logged out? I don't think I've encountered a site where there is any way to differentiate.

Comment: A user in a not *logged in* state is an "anonymous user".

Comment: @AndrewLeach, no, there's no difference between those two states. Hence I'm wondering if it's okay to call the people who just encountered the site as also being _logged out_.

Comment: @Graffito, would you say "anonymous user view"? Or just "anonymous view" then? (see example sentence)

Comment: It's not clear whether the expression is for internal use or for reading by a user.  If it's in a user interface, I don't think "anonymous [user] view" would be intelligible to many users.  "Some settings can be configured without logging in" would cover both unregistered & registered users.

Comment: 'Unauthenticated', 'unverified', 'unidentified'.

Comment: I would say that "anonymous users may configure some settings". You cannot use the expressions "anonymous/unregistred/... view" because these adjectives don't apply to the view.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Qs about "Naming, including naming programming variables/classes" are off-topic for this site.
See Help Centre at http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @TrevorD, I would think this is more a "Word choice and usage" question that applies in an online context... but I got some ideas from the comments, although no answers to "Is not logged in the same as logged out?" (which is a linguistic question, IMO)

Comment: "logged out" implies that a user was connected and the connection was terminated at his request or for another reason. "not logged" means either that the user didn't log in or that he didn't log out.

Comment: @Gerli - I agree with Garffito.  "logged out" implies that you have been logged in, but are no longer logged in.  "not logged in" could mean (a) you've logged out; or (b) you have never logged in (possibily because you do not have a registration for the site).

Comment: I agree with @TrevorD: "_not logged in_" could mean (**a**) you've logged out; or (**b**) you have never logged in (as yet). Maybe  **[unlogged](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unlogged)** is applicable, see also http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unlogged

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251800/a-word-for-a-non-logged-in-user

Comment: @HotLicks, I was looking for a word that would apply to the _state_ rather than the _user_. Yes, some of the answers there could apply to states as well but not really all of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The process of confirming a user's credentials and logging them in is often known as 'authentication'.  Therefore, a commonly accepted term for a user's state before logging in would be '**unauthenticated**'.  (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unauthenticated)

This would apply equally to registered and unregistered users as well as users that have failed to provide the correct tokens - in any of these cases authentication has not been completed.

A distinction can be made between 'not logged in' and 'logged out', in that 'logged out' may imply that the system has a record of a previous session where the user *was* logged in.

Comment: Op still hasn't addresses the issue I raised above on 13 April: namely, is the desired expression intended for for internal use or for reading by a user. If it's in a user interface, I there are many users (depending on the audience for the website) who would not immediately understand "anonymous [user] view", and I think the same may apply for "unauthenticated". – TrevorD Apr 13 at 10:58